# Visual Studio Code - make shortcut run only in editor focus

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a keyboard shortcut only run when focus is currently in the text editor, and specifically not in the VSCode file explorer sidebar.

I have observed all the examples in the keybindings.json and tried to follow their pattern.

The default binding in the default keybindings is as follows...

```
{ "key": "ctrl+n",                "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" },
```

The keyboard mapping I added in the user keybindings is as follows....

```
{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" , "when": "editorTextFocus && !filesExplorerFocus" }
```

But for some reason this is not working. Even when I have focus in the VSCode File Explorer menu, the command is still running.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I have tried unmapping the initial binding, which succeeds at removing the default binding. But when I add the new binding with the when clauses, the when clauses have no effect.

{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" , "when": "editorTextFocus && !filesExplorerFocus" },

{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "-workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile" },

Answer (score 1):

If you also disable the default keybinding it works as expected:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "-workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile"
}
```

Otherwise, when you have fileExplorerFocus, this command will be in scope and active.

Comment: Hmm, I tested it and it worked for me.  Put the disabled keybinding after your modified one.

Comment: I have tried both orders, and neither worked for me. I have updated the initial post to contain the new mappings.

Comment: I used just the unmapping and it worked, but the when clause of the new mapping is not working as expected. So even when focus is in the sidebar, the command is running.

Comment: In my case, I just re-mapped this one (`"-workbench......newUntitledFile"`) and the old one started to work. Also, I had this issue even with the fileExplorer closed.